# Can a HP P2000 G3 SAN with SAS controller direct connect to a Dell PowerEdge Server with a Dell brand HBA

Tags: storage-area-network, dell-poweredge, dell-perc, hp-modular-smart-array

I am building a home rig and have recently acquired an HP P2000 G3 SAN with SAS controllers. I appreciate these are supposed to connect into a DL380 G7 or G8 with the HP branded SAS interface card (sc08e) but I have a Dell PowerEdge R710 server. I'm wondering, if I purchased a dell SAS card like a Perc H200e, would I be able to directly connect the SAN in a similar way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically this question is off-topic if this is for home lab use - check out the [allowed topics](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

The question here is essentially whether the HP array will work with a Dell SAS HBA, or if an HP SAS HBA will work in a Dell server. Either one *should* work, but there's no guarantee. HP's rebranded LSI 9200-8e and Dell's rebranded 9207-8e both use the same LSI SAS 2008 chipset, so I would fully expect things to "work", though an HP card's firmware might not play nicely with Dell's system monitoring. Probably best to use the Dell 6Gbps SAS HBA or a generic LSI 9207-8e, as I doubt the HP array would have any mechanism to "disallow" non-approved HBAs from connecting.

Comment: That is excellent, many thanks. I appreciate it falls slightly off-topic and I apologise but as it involves enterprise level hardware I thought there may be some value for people who might have a similar situation in a business scenario.

Comment: Yeah, TBH these kinds of questions are usually 2 words away from being on topic by the letter of the law... e.g. "I am building a testing/learning lab rig". The site isn't strictly limited to production boxes, though that's certainly where the priority and focus are.